# php выполнить python-скрипт без консольных функций

Tags: php, python, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте.
Возникла проблема - необходимо из php выполнить некий python-скрипт и получить результат работы этого скрипта. Есть только одна проблема:
НЕ использовать консольные функции PHP (например exec, shell_exec,system,proc_​open).
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

**UPD:**
Небольшое уточнение. В роли python-скрипта выступает PyMorphy2 (https://github.com/kmike/pymorphy2), в него передаются данные, полученные извне через php+ajax, забирается результат и отдаётся обратно в php.
Основная проблема, как уже упоминал - не использовать консольные ф-и php/фреймворки. Лично у меня около 0 идей о том, как это делать.

Comment: d-bus python https://gist.github.com/caspian311/4676061#file-service-py php https://habrahabr.ru/post/165959/ client.php

Comment: позвольте полюбопытствовать, чем обусловлен отказ от консольных функций?

Comment: @lynx Требованиями тестового задания.

Comment: что такое "консольные функции"? К примеру, `pcntl_fork + pcntl_exec` к какой категории относится? Если средства самой операционной системы не хотите использовать, то к любому сервису, который Питон-код может выполнить, можно обратиться.